# Travar site na vertical

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

Como posso impedir que o conteúdo do *site* fique na horizontal quando o usuário virar o celular?

Teria alguma solução de *viewport* ou *javaScript*?

Comment: Isto deve ajudar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages

Comment: Já tentei, mas a tela ainda continua rotacionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas formas para fazer isso. A primeira que vc pode testar é esse *hake* de CSS, com ele quando vc muda a *view* para `landscape` ele gira a página -90%

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  html {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Na documentação oficial da W3C tem um material exclusive sobre orientação de tela. E eles têm alguns métodos para fazer um lock na orientação da tela
https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/

```
screen.orientation.lock('portrait')
screen.orientation.lock('landscape')
screen.orientation.unlock()
```

Exemplo completo para vc testar:

```
<script>
  var show = function() {
     console.log("Orientation type is " + screen.orientation.type);
     console.log("Orientation angle is " + screen.orientation.angle);
  }

  screen.orientation.addEventListener("change", show);
  window.onload = show;
</script>

<button onclick='screen.orientation.unlock()'>
  Unlock
</button>
<button onclick="screen.orientation.lock('portrait')">
  Lock to portrait
</button>
<button onclick="screen.orientation.lock('landscape')">
  Lock to landscape
</button>
```

---

A Mozilla também tem uma api para ajudar nisso como vc pode ver aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Managing_screen_orientation

```
screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
```

**Fica o aviso:** *Warning: This API is experimental and currently available on Firefox OS and Firefox for Android with a moz prefix, and for Internet Explorer on Windows 8.1 and above  with a ms prefix.*

No caso dos apps vc pode usar o Manifesto dessa forma para o FireFox

```
"orientation": "portrait"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/Firefox_OS_apps/Building_apps_for_Firefox_OS/Manifest#orientation

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tu executando esse código screen.orientation.lock('portrait') ao abrir a página, não deveria travar ela na vertical?

Comment: Diego pela documentação deveria travar sim, se não estiver funcionando, da uma olhada no link da documentação para ver se vc3 colocou tudo certinho, lá tem tudo explicado e alguns exemplos de como usar a api. Mas a Mozilla so garante o funcionamento como o FireFox ok!